# css: Isolate div element from other page styles

Tags: css

I have a browser extension that adds a div element (and others) to the page. Is there a way to make sure that the page styles don't affect the styles within my added element?

I've considered making it an iframe, but would prefer not to make the extra call. Making sure to overwrite every single possible style also seems a bit much, although my added information is just basic text and links.

Comment: Where does it add the div element? One way to do it would be to wrap all of the main page content in a div, then make each style only affect that wrapper div.

Comment: I cannot control the main page or its css (well, some via js, but prefer not to). I need my div to be absolute positioned in the upper right.

Comment: How is the new div added?

Comment: Can you put the code of it?

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(my_node);

Comment: I think you would just have to use a CSS reset, resetting all values by to the default (I think [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is a FULL reset). The only other option is to specify the other selectors to not affect the dynamically added elements

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you said you'd prefer not to use every style but I figured I should mention it here in case it helps someone else. Basically this is a class that can remove most inherited/predefined attributes. You can just add the class to any element you would want to exclude. Here is an example:

```
.reset {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    bottom:auto;
    clear:none;
    cursor:default;
    float:none;
    font-size:medium;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    height:auto;
    left:auto;
    letter-spacing:normal;
    line-height:normal;
    max-height:none;
    max-width:none;
    min-height:0;
    min-width:0;
    overflow:visible;
    position:static;
    right:auto;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-indent:0;
    text-transform:none;
    top:auto;
    visibility:visible;
    white-space:normal;
    width:auto;
    z-index:auto;
}
```

Now just add "reset" and it *should* set it back to normal. You can then define styles below that line and they will override the styles in the reset class.

You could also add a wildcard selector to the reset class so that is targets the element's children as well.

```
.reset,
.reset * { /*...etc */ }
```

NOTE: [Wildcards are supported by IE8+](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/universalselector#compatibilitysection), so if you are working on IE7 or lower - no dice.